# Azure storage account for SPA Application - Hash route problem

Tags: reactjs, azure

We have a React application on an Azure storage account as a static website. The application itself uses Hash Router as a routing strategy. The problem is when a user enters yourwebsite.com/login the user should be redirected to yourwebsite.com/#/login instead. Currently, it's not working that way instead, the user is looking for /login folder within the storage account.

Comment: If possible, can you please post the link to the website so we can see what may be the cause?

Comment: I wish I could it's a company policy and I cannot

Comment: I need something like this approach with PM2 https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/expose/#serving-spa-redirect-all-to-indexhtml to work properly